# Java string returns as null

Tags: java, string, methods, null, return

I am attempting to get one class to return a string from another class, though the return I get is null. I have a set method that works in setting the string in the original class, but when calling the method in my second class, I get a return of null.

Here is the first class;

```
public class IceCream
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String flavour;
    public static double price;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class IceCream
     */
    public IceCream()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        String flavour = getFlavour();
        price = 0.50;

    }

    /**
     * Gets price in pence.
     * 
     * 
     * @returns the price of the ice cream.
     */
    public static double getPrice()
    {
        // put your code here
        return price;
    }

    public int getScoops()
    {
        return scoop;
    }

public void setPrice(int newPrice)
{
    price = newPrice;
}

public void setScoops(int scoopNumber)
{
    scoop = scoopNumber;
}

public double totalCost()
{
    double cost;
    cost = scoop * price;
    return cost;

}

public String getFlavour()
{
  return flavour; 
}

public void setFlavour(String whatFlavour)
{
    flavour = whatFlavour;
}
```

}

And the second class, in which I am trying to call the string I input in the setFlavour method in the println of the sundaeDetails method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Write a description of class Sundae here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Sundae
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private IceCream flavour;
    private Topping SundaeTopping;
    private int scoops;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Sundae
     */
    public Sundae()
   {
     flavour = new IceCream();
     SundaeTopping = new Topping();
     scoops = 0;
   }
   /**
    * Set scoop number.
    */

    public void setScoops(int scoopNumber)
   {
    scoops = scoopNumber;
   }
   /**
    * Return scoop variable.
    */
   public int getScoops()
   {
       return scoops;
   }
   /**
    * Get the price of the sundae.
    */ 
   public void getPrice()
   {
        double cost;
        double scoopPrice = scoops * IceCream.getPrice();
        if ( scoops > 0) {
            cost = scoopPrice * Topping.getToppingPrice();
            System.out.println("Cost of Sundae: " + cost);
         }
        else {
        System.out.println("Need to have a scoop of ice cream in your Sundae.");
    }
    }

    /**
     * Return the details of the sundae; price, flavour, scoops etc.
     */
   public void sundaeDetails()
   {
       System.out.println("You have " + scoops + " scoops of " + flavour.getFlavour() + "ice cream");
   }
}
```

Comment: you never set the flavour

Comment: Unrelated: why is the price static?

Comment: Guessing that all `IceCream` objects have the same price.

Comment: In your constructor, you're shadowing `flavour`: `String flavour = getFlavour();`

Comment: @Marv if so, a constructor and an instance method should not be used to set the value of the price.

Comment: That is correct. @OP if this is in fact what you are trying to do, set the field `price` in the `IceCream` class directly.

Answer (score 1):

In IceCream class constructor you have:

```
String flavour = getFlavour()
```

You have created a local variable instead a reference to a instance property. getFlavour() method return the property instance that you never set, so its null. You should have something like this in the constructor:

```
this.flavour = "default value";
```

Or set a flavour parameter on constructor header:

```
public IceCream(String flavour) {
    this.flavour = flavour;
    (...)
}
```

And call it like:

```
IceCream chocolat = new IceCream(" chocolat");
```

And if you want change the flavour use the setter.

Answer (score 0):

You never call `flavour.setFlavour()`, so it's no surprise `flavour.getFlavour()` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Flavour is not initialized `private String flavour;` as anything, when calling `IceCream()` you set `String flavour = getFlavour()`, which sets the local variable `flavour` inside the constructor to null, because `getFlavour()` returns `null`. Also the local `String flavour` variable inside the constructor overshadows the `String flavour` field of your `IceCream` class. Try making flavour a parameter of the constructor and then setting the field to that string

```
public IceCream(String f) {
    this.flavour = f;
    price = 0.50;
}
```

or call `setFlavour()` before you work with the object you created.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts in the constructor of your IceCream class.

```
private String flavour;

public IceCream()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    String flavour = getFlavour();
    price = 0.50;
}

public String getFlavour()
{
  return flavour; 
}
```

The first problem is that you are shadowing your member variable `flavour` - you are declaring another variable with the same name but whose scope is restricted to the constructor. The second problem is you are assigning the value returned by `getFlavour()`, which is just an accessor that returns the member variable itself (whose initial value is null).

To fix it you need to assign an initial value in the constructor

```
public IceCream()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.flavour = "Vanilla"
    price = 0.50;
}
```

Its also possible to assign the initial value when you declare it

```
private String flavour = "Vanilla";
```

Comment: You mean `this.flavour = "Vanilla"`.